# Generic getters and setters of protected properties

Tags: typescript

Consider this TypeScript class that provides type checked generic getters and setters by splitting the implementation into super and sub classes:

```
class ICompetence {
    protected _id : number | undefined;
    protected name: string | undefined;
}

export default class Competence extends ICompetence {

    set<K extends keyof ICompetence>(key: K, value: ICompetence[K]): void {
        this[key] = value;
    }

    get<K extends keyof ICompetence>(key: K) : ICompetence[K] {
        return this[key];
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

The class is used like this:

```
let competence = new Competence():    
competence.set("name", "name value text");
```

However, then I receive this error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '"name"' is not assignable to parameter of type
```

The error can be overcome by removing the annotation protected from the interface class:

```
class ICompetence {
    _id : number | undefined;
    name: string | undefined;
}
```

Does TypeScript provide any feature to avoid this kind of error that occurs when the properties are protected?

Comment: Nope.`keyof` will just return public keys, not non public ones

Comment: It’s not an error... since you want to address `set` publicly, it has to be public... `competence.set("name", "name value text");`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `protected` only generates errors at design time and doesn't prevent accesses at runtime, you might get similar behavior another way, by *hiding* the relevant properties from your exported types, like this:

First, make the properties of the parent class public:

```
class ICompetence {
  _id: number | undefined;
  name: string | undefined;
}
```

Then extend the class normally, but don't export it, and rename it out of the way to `_Competence` (the "real" `Competence` will come later)

```
class _Competence extends ICompetence {

  otherProperty: string = "hmm"; // demonstrate you can add other things

  set<K extends keyof ICompetence>(key: K, value: ICompetence[K]): void {
    this[key] = value;
  }

  get<K extends keyof ICompetence>(key: K): ICompetence[K] {
    return this[key];
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

Now we prepare `Competence`.  First, we define the type function `Omit`, which removes the specified keys from a type:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
```

Then we export an interface named `Competence` and a value named `Competence`, which are derived from `_Competence` but do not expose the properties from `ICompetence`.  They're still there, of course, but the type system doesn't expose them:

```
export interface Competence extends Omit<_Competence, keyof ICompetence> { }
export const Competence = _Competence as new () => Competence;
```

Now in your consumer code you should be able to do something like this:

```
const competence = new Competence();
competence.name // error at compile time
competence.otherProperty // okay
const name = competence.get("name") // string or undefined
```

And it works.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot - it works! I had to upgrade my TypeScript to version 2.8. And I had to read the documentation closely to understand why it works. It's fantastic what can be done by TypeScript generics.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the idea in jcalz's answer but simplified the solution a bit:

```
class ICompetence { ... }

export class Competence extends ICompetence { ... }

type Omit<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
export interface Competence extends Omit<Competence, keyof ICompetence> { }
```

The solution then supports hiding client to access properties placed in class ICompetence while client can still access any propterty placed in subclass Competence.