# TS2322: Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: typescript-generics

I'm porting some JS to TS and have a simple app state module which allows me to set a property for later retrieval. When the ts compiler reaches the line `state[propertyName] = value;` inside the `setAppState` function, it throws the following error

> TS2322: Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'never'.

I searched for this error but none of the other answers seem to address this case where I'm setting an object property using bracket notation.

Here's my code...

```js
export interface appState {
  context: typeof cast.framework.CastReceiverContext,
  senderId: string,
  requestId: number,
  sessionId: string,
}

const state: appState = {
  context: null,
  senderId: null,
  requestId: null,
  sessionId: null,
};

export const getAppState = (propertyName: keyof appState): keyof appState => {
  return state[propertyName];
};

export const setAppState = <T>(propertyName: keyof appState, value: T): void => {
  state[propertyName] = value;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585492/generic-getters-and-setters-of-protected-properties/50599577#50599577) that showed the correct way to write the types in the function signatures for the generic getter and setter, which solves the problem. The following now compiles.

```js
export const getAppState = <K extends keyof appState>(propertyName: K): appState[K] => {
  return state[propertyName];
};

export const setAppState = <K extends keyof appState>(propertyName: K, value: appState[K]): void => {
  state[propertyName] = value;
};
```